# How to check block device supports `nowait` or not

Tags: linux, aio, block-device

I want to use async IO in my program. After some searching, I found [nowait](https://lwn.net/Articles/724198/) was added to avoid the blocking in aio. How can I check my system(block-device、plug, etc) supports `nowait` or not?

I am using ubuntu 22.04 with kernel version `6.2.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that today, you can't tell if a device supports NOWAIT I/O.

Inside the kernel, the block device queue will be tagged with `QUEUE_FLAG_NOWAIT` if it supports NOWAIT I/O.  You can query the flag state with `blk_queue_nowait`.  But, the flag isn't exposed to user space.  (It'd be a trivial patch though.)

That leaves you with trying to develop some sort of probe for NOWAIT support, but I'm afraid there isn't a straightforward answer there either.

- Nobody thought ahead to add a "reserved" section in the AIO `iocb` structure way back, so there's no way for older kernels that don't know about NOWAIT to say "no, I don't support this flag."  The flag just goes into the kernel and the kernel ignores it.
- Even in new kernels, when you specify `NOWAIT`, there's no "I don't support this" error return.  Instead, a few things can happen:

1. Most devices that lack support for it may simply return `EAGAIN` forever.  So, that's one probe you can try: do NOWAIT reads and see if the device ever handles one of them.
2. Some devices just ignore the flag.  It will be as if you were doing `NOWAIT` I/O on an older kernel with occasional blocking `io_submit` calls.
3. The devices that support NOWAIT I/O will complete the I/O's nearly all the time, but occasionally return `EAGAIN`.  That's what you're looking for.
   If you occasionally see `EAGAIN`, that indicates that NOWAIT is probably working.

I would offer that you might not need to worry about NOWAIT for a new application right off the bat.  Plan for `io_submit` to block for a few tens of microseconds.  If need be, put the I/O handling in its own thread.